# 50/50 inserts and selects. Create two tables or one table

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, database-performance

Now the proposed table structures are:-

```
data_table
->impressions
->clicks
->ctr
```

OR

```
data_table_1
->ctr

data_table_2
->impressions
->clicks
```

What queries are executed?
There are about 500 updates per second for the impressions. There is about 1 update for clicks every second. There are about 500 updates per second for the ctr.

Now my application sorts the data using the ctr. The ctr is the click through rate which is worked out by `ctr = clicks/impressions`. Now I have realised that unless there is a click update the ctr doesn't need to updated as all the impressions for articles are being increased which is decreasing the ctr in the same relationship, so unless there is a click the ctr does not need to be updated.

Currently the update query is like "UPDATE data_table SET impressions = impressions + 1, ctr = clicks / impressions WHERE something = something

This means that although 2 fields are updated at once only 1 query is executed.

Now the bottleneck is that these 500 updates on this causing slow down on selects on this table. There are about 20 selects per second. So I thought of separating the tables. The new table style proposes that the updates happen on a separate table and the selects happen on a separate table. The data table that contains the impressions is updated very frequently so having the updates for the impressions performed on it really speeds up the performance on this table. This means that the selects on the data_table_2 will be faster too and the ctr can be updated every time someone makes a click.

So, I just wanted to know if I should use the new table structure or not. What are you suggestions? Pros and Cons of my proposals!

Comment: Why does the `ctr` column even exist, considering that it's derived from the other columns?  Why can't you just use a view to project `ctr`?

Comment: What database engine are you using for these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not a direct answer to your question, but i think it's important to be noted.

I think you should consider using nosql databases like Redis, MemcacheDB, MongDB, CouchDB. Relatational DBMS are not well suitable for this kind of use. For example, every time you update any column (`UPDATE data_table SET impressions = impressions + 1`) the caches are erased, and the DB has to hit the disk.

Other think you can consider is using Memcache and bulk that data to disk after some period of time.

For example, if you can afford to loose some impresions (remember that memcache does not persist data) you can do the impresions++ in memcache and update data in the DB every 5 minutes. It would decrease your load significantly.

I hope it helps you.

**EDIT**:

Storing CTR is a good idea, it's called "Denormalization", and may work in your application if it's a frequently required value.

Comment: any insights on how can i use this model with php. I have considered this but the real problem is that i dont know how the update it "every 5 minutes" should be coded. I wouldn't like to use cron job.

Comment: Yes, you could use cron, it would be the best option. It depends on your server and the access/knowledge you have. If you can make cron work, do it that way! If not, then you should add some hardcoded work in your php script. You could store a timestamp in memcache and read from there, calculate some time and save to database if it's expired.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume the table is well indexed so the `something = something` predicate will quickly result in the corresponding row, right?

Further assuming that your bottleneck is disk-throughput because of the high update rate, what about not storing the ctr value at all, as it can be easily calculated on the fly? Since you seem to be limited by your update, only updating one field should roughly half the impact of having to write data to the disk. Given such scenario, where the CPU is probably relatively idle, calculating click/impressions for every result should be a non-issue. Your approach would pay off (again assuming disk is the limiting factor, which assume it is and can be found out easily by looking at CPU utilization), then your approach will give considerable benefits, *iff* the tables or on two different disks.

If the CPU turns out to be the limiting factor, then it's probably because the `something = something` predicate is quite complicated to evaluate in which case simplifying this should be the main concern, and not splitting the tables.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the cpu usage is below 50%. the bottleneck is the high number of updates.

Comment: @Anush, you haven't answered Michael's question. Is the table using MyISAM or InnodB engine?

Comment: Innodb crashes? That's mighty strange, isn't it?